# Algebra in R: Vectorization vs. foreach vs. sapply

Tags: r, algebra

I have a series of equation systems with sums and products of vectors, matrices and arrays, such as this one:

```
Y_i = \sum_{s=1}^S (1-alpha_{i,s})*R_i,
```

where `Y` and `R` are vectors of length `I` with elements `Y_i` and `R_i`, respectively, and `alpha` is a matrix with `I` rows and `S` columns.

Now I'd like to implement those equations in R, but doing so with a reasonable level of 'mathematical readability'. In particular, I'm not looking for the shortest or the fastest executing chunk of code, but one that mirrors the original mathematical expression intuitively. For the example above, I know that a quick and easy way to compute the vector Y would be vectorization:

```
Y <- rowSums((1-alpha)*R)
```

However, with more complicated expressions with more operations and more dimensions in mind, I find it much more intuitive to basically copy the equation on paper using `foreach` loops across the involved dimensions like this:

```
library(foreach)
Y <- foreach(i = 1:I, .combine = c) %:%
    foreach(s = 1:S, .combine = sum) %do% {
        (1-alpha[i,s])*R[i]
    }
```

I really like the structure and the .combine argument here, and the code is still somewhat concise. Unfortunately, the performance of this approach is terrible, which sadly makes it unfeasible. I then experimented with `sapply` loops:

```
Y <- sapply(1:I, function(i) {
    sum(
        sapply(1:S, function(s) {
            (1-alpha[i,s])*R[i]
        })
    )
})
```

This approach is both fast (not as fast as the vectorized approach, but way faster than the `foreach` apprach) and mathematically intuitive; however, the code is quite clunky to read (seven lines for only two dimensions). I would therefore like to ask: Can you think of a preferable alternative approach to solve this problem (and more complicated variants thereof) without sacrificing too much of either computational speed, mathematical intuition or code readability?

Comment: "preferable" is vague enough to make this too opinion-based. If you can vectorize the calculation and it is faster than the alternatives, why not stick with that? Intuition and readability come with experience. R itself isn't the most intuitive and readable programming language. If you have found an idiomatic (in the R sense) way to make it work, why worry?

Comment: I don't believe your goal is reasonable (or even can be achieved in general). In any case, it would need to be defined much more clearly and specifically. Also, you need to consider floating point precision, too. In some applications that would be more important than all your other concerns.

Comment: If you want code readability or mathematical intuition, it's better to translate the math language to your code straightforwardly, e.g., nested `for` loops. If you care more about the computational speed, you should reformulate the math language and optimize it as the first step, which pays at the price of readability. Two aspects are trade-off. Depends on what you really pursue.

Comment: One thing you can do is create custom functions that are more readable. I do that all the time. Then you have readable top-line code that you can deep dive into.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. My main concern was that there might be a (function/package/variant of what I'm already doing) that I do not know yet but which does exactly what I want. Unfortunately, I guess that is not the case. I agree with @JohnColeman that eventually, with some experience, it will be easy enough to just write down the vectorized version immediately without thinking too much. For now, I'll keep working with the `sapply` loops to test my code and then later revise it by introducing vectorization where I see fit. Thanks for the discussion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) for** Vectorizing just the inner loop will give something very close to the original.  (We use the inputs in the Note at the end.)

```
I <- nrow(alpha)
Y <- numeric(I)
for(i in 1:I) Y[i] <- sum((1 - alpha[i, ]) * R[i])
## [1] -144 -240  -44 -144 -260 -112
```

**2) sapply** and this would also work using a similar approach:

```
I <- nrow(alpha)
Y <- sapply(1:I, function(i) sum((1 - alpha[i, ]) * R[i]))
## [1] -144 -240  -44 -144 -260 -112
```

**3) fn$** Prefacing a function with fn$ from the gsubfn package will allow functions passed in arguments to be specified as formulas so we can write:

```
library(gsubfn)

I <- nrow(alpha)
S <- ncol(alpha)
fn$sapply(1:I, i ~ sum(fn$sapply(1:S, s ~ (1 - alpha[i, s]) * R[i])))
## [1] -144 -240  -44 -144 -260 -112
```

or for even greater brevity we define `iter` as shown and also use gsubfn's multiple assignment facility to define I and S at once.

```
library(gsubfn)

iter <- fn$sapply
list[I, S] <- dim(alpha)

iter(1:I, i ~ sum(iter(1:S, s ~ (1 - alpha[i, s]) * R[i])))
## [1] -144 -240  -44 -144 -260 -112
```

**4) Comprehensions**   There are 3 packages on CRAN that support python-like comprehensions with certain modifications to syntax.  There is also some code posted [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2007-December/047697.html) and [here](https://gist.github.com/klmr/35a13344080e71bf8c34) and a github only package lc [here](https://github.com/mailund/lc) which we will not review.  The packages are listed below in alphabetical order.

**4a) comprehenr**

```
library(comprehenr)
packageVersion("comprehenr") # be sure to use version 0.6.9 or later

I <- nrow(alpha)
to_vec(for(i in 1:I) sum((1-alpha[i, ])*R[i]))
## [1] -144 -240  -44 -144 -260 -112
```

or with two indexes:

```
I <- nrow(alpha)
J <- ncol(alpha)
to_vec(for(i in 1:I) sum(to_vec(for(j in 1:J) (1-alpha[i, j])*R[i])))
## [1] -144 -240  -44 -144 -260 -112
```

**4b) eList** There is a new package out, eList, that supports list and vector comprehensions. A notable feature of this package (not shown here) is that it supports parallel processing with only a minor change in arguments.

```
library(eList)
packageVersion("eList") # be sure to use version 0.2,0 or later

I <- nrow(alpha)
Num(for (i in 1:I) sum((1-alpha[i, ])*R[i]))
## [1] -144 -240  -44 -144 -260 -112
```

or using both i and s:

```
library(eList)

I <- nrow(alpha)
S <- ncol(alpha)

Num(for(i in 1:I) Sum(for(s in 1:S) (1-alpha[i,s]) * R[i]))
## [1] -144 -240  -44 -144 -260 -112
```

**4c) listcompr**  This is another package that supports comprehensions. It has a slightly different syntax than than the above two being somewhat closer to Python.

```
library(listcompr)

I <- nrow(alpha)
gen.vector(sum((1-alpha[i, ])*R[i]), i = 1:I)
## [1] -144 -240  -44 -144 -260 -112
```

or using both indices:

```
I <- nrow(alpha)
J <- ncol(alpha)
gen.vector(sum(gen.vector((1-alpha[i, j])*R[i], j = 1:J)), i = 1:I)
## [1] -144 -240  -44 -144 -260 -112
```

**5) nimble** If the above are not fast enough we could consider using the nimble package which will translate R-like code plus some type definitions into C++ .

```
library(nimble)

calc <- nimbleFunction(
  run = function(alpha = double(2), R = double(1)) {
    I <- dim(alpha)[1]
    Y <- numeric(I)
    for(i in 1:I) Y[i] <- sum((1 - alpha[i, ]) * R[i])
    return(Y)
    returnType(double(1))
  }
)

Ccalc <- compileNimble(calc)

# test
Ccalc(alpha, R)
## [1] -144 -240  -44 -144 -260 -112
```

**6) einsum** The einsum package supports Einstein tensor notation.  The left hand side of the first argument is separated into two groups by a comma and each group defines the indexes in one of the inputs in the subsequent arguments.  The index on the right hand side is the corresponding index of the output.  This package has the ability to generate C++ code and then execute it (not shown here).

```
library(einsum)

einsum("ij,i -> i", 1-alpha, R)
## [1] -144 -240  -44 -144 -260 -112
```

### Note

Some inputs to use for testing:

```
alpha <- matrix(1:24, 6)
R <- c(4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 2)
```

### Update

Have rearranged presentation, added additional approaches and updated section on comprehensions in light of new versions and an additional find.

Comment: Thanks, especially for hinting me at `eList` and `nimble`. A quick query: How would I implement the full nested loop using `eList` syntax? I got as far as `Num(for (i in 1:I) for (s in 1:S) (1-alpha[i,s])*R[i])`, but can't figure out how to sum across the `s` dimension within the loop, without just applying an outer `rowSums`.

Comment: If has a `Sum` operator and if it worked it would presumably be `Num(for(i in 1:I) Sum(for(s in 1:S) (1-alpha[i,s]) * R[i]))` but it seems this sort of nested comprehension does not work at package version 0.0.1.0.  At the time I answered the question I did send the author an email pointing out the issue.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I tried as well. `Sum` and `Prod` would indeed be handy to have as operators. In any case, I still need to see how easily I can get accustomed to the various different approaches. My current strategy would probably be to start with `eList`/`sapply` for mathematical intuition, later try to vectorize whatever I can, and eventually switch to `nimble`/`Rcpp` for that final performance boost. I'll keep the question open for a little longer to allow other people to post their ideas.

Comment: Added the einsum package.